# Dynamically display selected option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've seen related questions but they don't help me a lot.
I want to display the selected option in the table.

I use function **admin_items()** to fill out the options from the table, and I need to pass selected value to the **show_editable()** function

```
function admin_items() {
  $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Items";
  $result_set = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
  $num_rows = $result_set->num_rows;
  $array = array();
  $i = 1;
  echo "<h2>Select item to change:</h2>\n<select name='movie_list'>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    echo "<option value =\"" . $row['ID']. "\">" . $row['ProductName']. "</option>";
  }
  $mysqli->close();
  echo "</select><hr />";
}



function show_editable(){
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  echo("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = 1";//I would like to pass selected value here
$result_set = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$num_rows = $result_set->num_rows;
echo "<br /><h3>Selected Item:</h3>\n
  <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"post\">
  <table class='admin'>
    <tr class='header'>  
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr> ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
  echo "<tr><td><textarea style=\"resize:none\" type=\"text\" name=\"ProductName" . $row['ID'] . "\" cols=22 rows=3>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea type=\"text\" name=\"Description" . $row['ID'] . "\" cols=80 rows=10>" . $row['Description'] . "</textarea></td>
  <td><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"4\" size=\"4\" name=\"Quantity" . $row['phoneID'] . "\" value=\"" . $row['Quantity'] . "\" /></td>
  <td><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"4\" size=\"4\" name=\"Price" . $row['phoneID'] . "\"      value=\"" . $row['Price'] . "\" /></td>
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"goedit\" value=\" Edit Field(s) \" /><br />";

echo "</form><br /><hr />";

$mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: selected value is visible only to client side (javascript) until you click some button to send it to server side. If you want this to show info about selected item before submit use jquery and ajax to retrieve data.

Comment: You're doing it very wrong. First of all - you should at least separate HTML from PHP, second - you don't have to connect to db all the time from random functions, third - you'd better start using a framework like Laravel 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u will need to split the two functions into different files

The `admin_items()` should be run during loading the page so that the options can be populated

Then when ever the user choose from the options, post an ajax call to run the `show_editable()`.

```
$('#your_dropdown_id').on('change', function(){
              $.ajax({
                'type' : 'post',
                'data':{'id': $(this).val()},
                'url' : '../show_editable',//point to the show_editable()
                'success' : function(data)
                {
                    $('place_that_should_contain_the_html_codes').html(data);
                }
            });
});
```

Then in your show_editable() function, just add one line to get the posted ID:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];//the key for the param is up to u to define
```

and echo the HTML codes.

Then the JavaScript will do the `onSuccess` and finish the rest.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've split functions into 2 files and used global variables to pass them.
I didn't want to bother with ajax.
So I made my own solution, but you gave me an idea. Thanks!